# Starting with git and I have some questions

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, git

I'm trying to bring myself to use git to develop my web apps, I develop alone since I'm still learning. I was wondering if this workflow would be a good start for me. Basically I have the master branch, this would be also called the production branch were only safe and working code resides, then I could have a develop branch, this branch is were I do all my day to day work, on this branch I could be adding new features, fixes, everything as  branches and I guess this new branches off develop could be merged with master? or maybe merged with develop and back to master? what would be the best solution?

I'm open to suggestions of all kinds.

Comment: I'd do exactly as you said but never merge any tertiary (feature) branch into master directly. Always merge into develop and make sure it works with the existing code there before moving it to the production branch. Also, commit  early and often -- basically as many, small commits as you can. I don't have much experience with git myself, but this is what I think I know so far.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a simplified version of git-flow https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: you can have a development and production branches, push all the work onto the dev branch, making sure it works as intended, then merge onto the production branch

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is a good start for web-develop
when you have developed and completed the function,you can merge the developing branch with the master branch.
Our company and our group use this way to develop
What's more,we have a branch for test.There are three branch in all
master branch;develop branch and test branch
We develop in the develop branch.When we finish a function,it is merge with test branch.
When the tester finish their work,test branch is merge with master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a master branch(locked with merge privileges only to a few) and a development branch, which is merged to master after the end-of-sprint or development-completion.

1. For every new feature, you can create a branch off development, and can merge it to development once you have the satisfaction that it is ready-to-be-merged. Eg. `git checkout -b feature/search-feature`
2. For bug fixes related to already merged branch, you can open up a bug fix branch with actual branch's name: Eg: `git checkout -b bugfix/search-feature`
3. For hotfixes that you make to server after it is deployed because you figured something was broken, you can probably have hotfix prefix. Eg: hotfix/broken-issue
4. I strongly suggest meaningful commit messages instead commit message that says "Fixes", "Fixed Issues" because when you look back to surf through or cherry pick commits, it will be very handy. Eg: `git commit -m "Fixed [your issue] in [your functionality]".`

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a lot 3 main branched. master, staging and development.

All new features will be merged into development that could potentially have issues. Once Sprint is completed then freeze code and merge into staging where final testing is done. Now development continues to live its own life and does not introduce any new issues into code during testing phase. Once tested then merge to master that will be released.

This way master is always ready for hotfixes. If hotfixes occur then merge these from master to staging to development.